# Combine Multiple string-array from array.xml to one single List

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I have some string-array defined in the array.xml, and want to combine them in to a single List. I have try like this:

```
List<String> name_list;
name_list = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name1));
name_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name2)));
```

But error `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

**array.xml**

```
<string-array name="name1">
    <item>Peter</item>
    <item>Phooenix</item>
    <item>Ebele</item>
    <item>Alice</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="name2">
    <item>Olivia</item>
    <item>Tai</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the Javadoc of [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) you can see that the List returned by `Arrays.asList(...)` is only a Bridge to use an Array as a List and therefore is fixed size.

To solve your problem you can use something like this:

```
List<String> name_list = new ArrayList<>();
name_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name1)));
name_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name2)));
```

Comment: But doing like this will become `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @MayWong The only way you'd get NPE with that code is if `getResources()` or `getStringArray()` return `null`, and you haven't included the code for either, so we can't help with that. If you need help with that, ask a new question, because *this* question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Read the javadocs on Arrays.asList:

Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

So you're not allowed to call addAll in the second line of your code. Instead, you need to create your own List, and use addAll for both arrays on your own list.

Comment: Do you have any other ways to do this?

Comment: Other way could be, changing 2nd line to - 

`name_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name1)));`